# ASK MySQL Query SUM different table

Tags: mysql, sum

Hello i want to ask about sum query, I experienced confusion when performing a query.

I want to calculate the total current.

SUM For INCOMING Material

```
select (select sum(jumlah) from  warehouse where tgl_invoice >= '2013-03-17' AND
tgl_invoice <='2013-03;18' and kode=a.kode) total,a.kode,a.nama from warehouse a 
group by a.kode;
```

Result :

---

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| total | kode    | nama       |
+-------+---------+------------+
|     4 | ACLG001 | AC LG 1 pk |
|   180 | P001    | Spindle    |
|    40 | S012    | Cable      |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

SUM For **use of material (goods)**

```
select (select sum(jumlah) from use_material where tanggal >= '2013-03-17' AND 
tanggal <='2013-03;18' and kode_barang=a.kode)  total,a.kode,a.nama from warehouse a
group by a.kode;
```

Result :

---

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| total | kode    | nama       |
+-------+---------+------------+
|  NULL | ACLG001 | AC LG 1 pk |
|    20 | P001    | Spindle    |
|    10 | S012    | Cable      |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

And now I want to SUM **Incoming Material(goods)** minus **use of material (goods)**

```
  select 
  (select sum(jumlah) from  warehouse 
  where tgl_invoice >= '2013-03-17' AND tgl_invoice <='2013-03;18' and kode=a.kode) -
  (select sum(jumlah) from use_material 
  where tanggal >= '2013-03-17' AND tanggal <='2013-03;18' and kode_barang=a.kode)
  total,a.kode,a.nama from warehouse a group by a.kode;
```

Result :

---

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| total | kode    | nama       |
+-------+---------+------------+
|  NULL | ACLG001 | AC LG 1 pk |
|   160 | P001    | Spindle    |
|    30 | S012    | Cable      |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

In here is an error in calculating. should AC LG 1 PK must be valued 4. but in result NULL

Please Answer.

Answer (score 1):

SQL COALESCE - to kill the null value should help.

e.g. COALESCE(NULL,0) will give 0... doing operations with NULL will often not work.

By this, I mean you wrap the null-yielding query (the second query you showed) in a COALESCE with a 0 to give a valid subtraction statement.

Cheers.

Comment: how to use COALESCE statement

Comment: TRY:    select COALESCE(select sum(jumlah) from use_material where tanggal >= '2013-03-17' AND 
tanggal <='2013-03;18' and kode_barang=a.kode),0)  total,a.kode,a.nama from warehouse a
group by a.kode;

Comment: Essentially COALESCE takes parameters and it simply returns the first non-null value provided. It's used _precisely_ for this kind of thing. You cannot subtract null from something. You get null... so you COALESCE with 0 to get something you _can_ use. Hope it helps at all.

Comment: Thanks bro, it's work.

select COALESCE((select sum(jumlah) from use_material where tanggal >= '2013-03-17' AND tanggal <='2013-03;18' and kode_barang=a.kode),0) total,a.kode,a.nama from warehouse a group by a.kode;

Comment: Cool. No worries, mate. Go ahead and click that 'tick as answer' button?

Comment: I want to ask again, but i can't answer until 6 hours again :(

Answer (score 0):

select IFNULL(t.total,0,t.total), a.kode, a.nama from warehouse a
left join (select kode_barang kode_barang,sum(jumlah) as total from use_material
        where tanggal >= '2013-03-17' AND tanggal <='2013-03-18' 
        group by kode_barang)  as t on t.kode_barang=a.kode
group by a.kode;